# Find substring from a string

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql database. I want to extract the substring from a string, provided the string contains a character ('/'). If the string doesn't contains '/' character in it, it should return a void string.

For example suppose string is `MY_FILE_PATH_CODE/dir1/dir2`

**query is**

```
select substr(string,instr(string ,'/')) from ( select string  from ac1_control );
   Return value : /dir1/dir2 (correct as i want)
```

And problem is if my string is only `MY_FILE_PATH_CODE`, then the same query returns `MY_FILE_PATH_CODE` that I don't want, I want return to be a void string.

Comment: void string means - no character inside the string.( e.g "")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to check for that explicitly, maybe like this:

```
select (case when instr(string, '/') = 0 then "" else substr(string, instr(string, '/')) end) from ( select string from ac1_control )
```

Comment: I was trying to fit your solution in my complex query.
Thanks .. it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

In oracle :
[*based on assumption that void string is null and using your orig. string*]

```
SELECT REPLACE ( SUBSTR('MY_FILE_PATH_CODE',INSTR('MY_FILE_PATH_CODE','/') ),
                'MY_FILE_PATH_CODE') 
  FROM dual;
```